# (The) unemployment in the country has fallen recently

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I have been recently wondering about the reason why is "the" omitted in such a phrase like the one quoted below.

"The unemployment in the country has fallen recently."

My understanding of the English articles makes me believe that "the" in this sentence is required since we want to specify the particular unemployment in a particular country. I think it is quite different from saying a sentence like this:

"Unemployment has become a serious threat for the country".

Here, the concept of unemployment is generalized and not limited to the boundaries of a specific country, even though it affects this country.

Nevertheless, why searching the Google results, I have found out that the phrase "The unemployment in the country" has been used only 7 times on co.uk sites, whereas "unemployment in the country" as many as 19 900 times.
Certainly, some of the results can include phrases like "the highest rate of unemployment in the country", but still the difference is discernible.

My questions are:

1. Can "the unemployment in the country has fallen recently" be treated as grammatically correct?

1.1 . If yes, what is the difference between this one and the one without "the"?

1.2 . If not, why is that?

Comment: Admittedly the number of hits are still low, but if you Google the names of British cities in place of "country" you'll have more supporting data: [**the unemployment in Manchester**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+unemployment+in+Manchester%22&sxsrf=APwXEdfK9txHzHa_PMxFYfjWg1O37PAqsQ%3A1679838713297&ei=-U0gZLXsEf2Xxc8Pv_ujsA0&ved=0ahUKEwj1zKTu3vn9AhX9S_EDHb_9CNYQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22the+unemployment+in+Manchester%22&gs_lcp=gws-wiz-serp)

Comment: The figures I see are "unemployment in the country":  3 620 000 // "the unemployment in the country": 620 000. The addition of the article blocks examples such as "the worst/high/worrying  rate of unemployment in the country" / "the rate of unemployment in the country" /  "[the] ten areas of lowest unemployment in the country"

Comment: hits on phrases do not provide adequate context...

Answer (score 0):

As  general guidance, uncountable nouns do not require a determiner but ***may*** take one:

“Unemployment has remained high despite government efforts.”

Note that this is a general reference to unemployment as a concept.

If the uncountable noun is defined/specified, either by a relative clause, an adjunct or an adjective then “The” ***may*** be used to indicate that the listener should know of, or has been made aware of, the specific type of uncountable noun, and particularly if the uncountable noun has been previously mentioned.

“The unemployment **that has dogged the economy** has remained high despite government efforts.”

“The unemployment **in the area** has remained high despite government efforts.”

“The **widespread** unemployment has remained high despite government efforts.”

> Can "the unemployment in the country has fallen recently" be treated as grammatically correct?

Yes, note the use of “***may***” above.

Comment: Could you find us some attested examples that are actually used in news articles rather than make up your own?

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive explanation. Why is then, the version without "the" much more common that the one with the definite article? Do people prefer to look at the concept as general as long as it is not specified by the  "the he...of" phrase or defining clause?

Comment: @Penguin422 *Why is then, the version without "the" much more common that the one with the definite article?* As I mentioned, "The" is licensed when the uncountable noun is defined or specified and "unemployment" is usually defined or specified.

Comment: Can you beat it? You basically said exactly what I said before you said it.

Comment: @Lambie - Er... no, I didn't - you referred to *abstract* rather than *uncountable* nouns, and you did not note the partitive effect of adjectivals and how that licenses "the".

Comment: Yes, abstract, but I gave three examples of how you can have determiners with an abstract noun. I prefer abstract: Abstract nouns vs. concrete nouns
We dive deep into abstract nouns vs. concrete nouns here, but there’s a quick and easy way to tell them apart. If you can see, hear, taste, smell, or touch it, then it’s a concrete noun. If you can’t, then it’s an abstract noun. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/abstract-nouns/

Answer (score 0):

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unemployment), *unemployment* is defined as:

> 1 : the state of being unemployed : involuntary idleness of workers
> also : **the rate of such unemployment**
> 2 : UNEMPLOYMENT COMPENSATION

(Boldface mine.)

And you're asking about "the rate of such unemployment". In this particular meaning, *unemployment* alone is not normally accompanied by the definite article even with the following phrase such as *in the country*, unless also accompanied by *rate*, as in:

> *The unemployment rate (in the country) has fallen recently.*

So, your sentence is very unidiomatic and virtually ungrammatical:

> ??*The unemployment in the country has fallen recently.*

Comment: I find the answer lacking in precision. We *can* use the definite article if the noun is preceded by a quantifier and we are specifying which unemployment e.g unemployment among white-collar workers   "**Most/nearly all/some/hardly any/none** [of the] unemployment is affected by…”

Comment: I read your now-deleted comment. Here is some proof: [**Most of the unemployment in Finland is** in the industrial, technical, … and office work sectors.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22most+of+the+unemployment%E2%80%9D+&sxsrf=APwXEddR2iRTGSnQBlTlxrlfBDVStV6ntw%3A1679831195669&ei=mzAgZPWwKL3_7_UP5d2J0Aw&ved=0ahUKEwi16sztwvn9AhW9_7sIHeVuAsoQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22most+of+the+unemployment%E2%80%9D+&gs_lcp=gws-wiz-serp)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I find the answer lacking in precision. :) I think in your example _the unemployment_ doesn't mean _the unemployment rate_. So it's neither here nor there.

Comment: The OP is asking why the definite article is missing from **such a phrase** as “(The) unemployment in the country has fallen…” Its scope is not confined to the meaning of  "rate" as  your answer might lead learners to believe, “…unless also accompanied by rate…” IMO that is inaccurate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then why don't you go ahead and write up an answer? And when you do that, don't forget to cite an example where "the unemployment" meaning "the rate" is indeed in use, if you can.

Comment: I don't think I could add anything particularly significant which Greybeard's answer doesn't imply or mention.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But Greybeard's answer erroneously concludes that "the unemployment in the country has fallen recently" is fine and "the" is merely optional, which is not true at all. So the answer not just lacks precision but is plain wrong. And OP's comment under the answer shows that OP doesn't really understand why "The unemployment in the country" is virtually non-existent compared with "unemployment in the country".

Comment: Greybeard did not say "the" is *always* fine, they said the definite article **may** be used when the noun has been previously mentioned.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The is not needed for unemployment based on whether is has been previously mentioned. That is not accurate. If you are teaching a course on unemployment, you might mention it several times in a paragraph with no determiner.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why do you keep ignoring the fact that Greybeard concluded that "the unemployment in the country has fallen recently" is fine (when it's not!)?

Comment: This: "The unemployment in the country has fallen recently. is not unidiomatic" is mistaken. It's alright but the the is not usually needed.

Comment: @Lambie If you mean "your sentence is very unidiomatic" is mistaken, please give me an attested example of a similar construction, where _unemployment_ meaning "the rate" is used with "the" without "rate".

Comment: @JK2  Your comment to Mari-Lou was very confusing. I tried to reproduce it as **you wrote it**. And to say that I do not agree with your disagreement. [over and out]

Comment: @Lambie I don't know what you're trying to say, but I've never said what you quoted me as saying. I've never said "The unemployment in the country has fallen recently. is not unidiomatic". Please let me know where I've said that.

Comment: @JK2 In your answer: "So, your sentence is very unidiomatic and virtually ungrammatical:??The unemployment in the country has fallen recently."

Comment: @Lambie You had said "Your comment to Mari-Lou was very confusing. I tried to reproduce it as you wrote it." Then, you said it was not my comment but my answer that you were responding to. As I have already said to Mari-Lou and you--and I repeat--please give me an attested example of a similar construction, where unemployment meaning "the rate" is used with "the" without "rate". If the sentence is idiomatic, you should be able to find some attested examples from, say, reputable news papers.

Comment: @JK2 Here's an example of usage: **The first step in attempting to reduce *unemployment* is to identify *the causes of the unemployment in the country*, as this will ultimately influence the policies to be implemented to reduce *unemployment*.** An International Monetary Fund presentation by the Central Bank of Swaziland. The PPT also has a bunch of "the rate of unemployment". By the way, unemployment can mean absolute numbers, and not rate necessarily.

Comment: https://www.imf.org/external/np/seminars/eng/2016/smic/presentations/S2EdwardDlamini.ppt

Comment: @Lambie In your example, _the causes of the unemployment in the country_ cannot mean "the causes of the unemployment rate in the country".

Comment: @JK2 I know that.  Go read the paper: it has all combinations:  unemployment, the unemployment + the unemployment rate. An unemployment **rate** is not unemployment (actual number of unemployed). Obviously.

Comment: @Lambie Why should I be reading the paper when you can't even cite a single sentence containing "the unemployment" meaning "the unemployment rate"?

Comment: @JK2 "Unemployment" **cannot mean** unemployment rate. Just like a **discount rate** is not **a discount**.

Comment: @Lambie Say that to M-W editors.

Answer (score 0):

The figures I see in general Google searches are:

- "unemployment in the country":  3 620 000
- "the unemployment in the country": 620 000.

So, not forgetting to subtract, the ratio of the usages

"unemployment in the country": "[no 'the'] unemployment in the country" is about 1 : 5.

However, the addition of the article blocks many anarthrous examples such as

- "the worst/high/worrying  rate of unemployment in the country"
- "the rate of unemployment in the country"
- "[the] ten areas of lowest unemployment in the country"
- "create jobs to eradicate youth unemployment in the country".

and will, one would expect, be heavily skewed.

Semantically, I'd agree that there *is* a difference between the two variants. But this is not shown in the following, where 'unemployment' = 'unemployment figures/levels':

- Unemployment in the country has fallen recently.
- Unemployment figures in the country have fallen recently.
- The unemployment in the country has fallen recently.
- The unemployment figures in the country have fallen recently.
- Unemployment in Germany has fallen recently.
- Unemployment figures in Germany have fallen recently.
- The unemployment in Germany has fallen recently.
- The unemployment figures in Germany have fallen recently.

Each of the above is totally idiomatic, and as suggested, the definite article is licensed as there is [post-]specification of 'unemployment figures'. But the null article, Ø₂, which 'looks exactly like' the zero article, Ø₁, is commonly used as an alternative in this case. It is the most definite of the articles. See [Master: Acquisition of the Zero and Null Articles in English](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2kb4p9r0) & qv.

This usage is not particularly rare:

- [The] beer in Germany is very different from that in England.
- Charles became [the] King of England immediately.
- It's difficult to say [the] barometric pressure is *solely* responsible for extra aches and pains.

....................

On the other hand, with your other example,

- "Unemployment has become a serious threat for the country."

as you say, there is no immediate specification, and this sense is 'the state of people, especially in appreciable numbers, being out of work' sense, so the definite article (and correspondingly, one could argue, the null article (Ø₂)) are inappropriate. But the zero article is indistinguishable at first glance from the null article.

Compare

- "Covid is a serious threat to the country."
- "Anxiety is a major issue in terms of wellbeing and also productivity at work." [[Facebook](https://m.facebook.com/HackingHR/posts/anxiety-is-a-major-issue-in-terms-of-wellbeing-and-also-productivity-at-work-act/413184742561470/)]

Answer (score -2):

Abstract nouns do not require determiners.

For those who insist on a reference:

[abstract nouns_Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/abstract-nouns/)

For example, from that text:

life

death

humor

independence

communication

information

honor

trust

Employment, unemployment and wealth are other examples.

Of course, in some instances, you might use it but **in general a determiner is not needed** if you are referring to the basic notion of the abstract noun.

- Wealth is often a good thing.
- **The** wealth **of this country** is tied up in crazy financial assets.
- **Unemployment** can be a serious issue in some places.
- **The unemployment** in this country has fallen recently. [same structure as the sentence above this and can be used with the the determiner]
- A better type of wealth might be in the works; if only economists would analyze it.

Comment: Where in the link do they say "Abstract nouns do not require determiners"?

Comment: The examples **show it**: **Time** flies when you’re having fun. No one wins without **talent**.  “**Success** is not final; **failure** is not fatal.” —Winston Churchill

Comment: Then that's an oversimplification. It's problematic if you classify nouns based on their semantics, as your link does. For example, "idea" does denote an abstract concept, but it's generally treated as a count noun. (Note 'concept' is a count noun as just shown!)

Comment: @JK2 You misread the link., The link has the word **Ideas** above the list it gives of abstract nouns. And of course idea is a countable noun. Gees.

Comment: _Idea_ is of course a count noun. But according to the link, "Abstract nouns represent intangible ideas—things you can’t perceive with the five main senses." Thus, _idea_ is an abstract noun, yet it's a count noun.

Comment: @JK2 Abstract nouns are ideas and concepts that you cannot touch, such as happiness, democracy and wisdom. British Council https://www.britishcouncilfoundation.id/en/english/articles/grammar-terms And those examples function like unemployment, you can't touch it.

Comment: That's the definition of an 'abstract noun'. According to that definition, _idea_ is also an abstract noun because you can't touch it. But it's always a count noun. So the concept of 'abstract noun' is not helpful in determining whether you need an article (or determiner).

Comment: @JK2 **"An abstract noun identifies an object that you cannot see, touch, or count. There are some exceptions, but most abstract nouns cannot be made plural, so they are noncount nouns. Examples of abstract nouns include anger, education, melancholy, softness, violence, and conduct".** And of course, employment, unemployment etc. https://open.lib.umn.edu/writingforsuccess/chapter/5-3-count-and-noncount-nouns-and-articles/#:~:text=An%20abstract%20noun%20identifies%20an,softness%2C%20violence%2C%20and%20conduct.

Comment: I've not downvoted, but have removed the 'over-harsh-corrective' upvote I gave. 'Abstract nouns do not require determiners' is demonstrably not the whole truth, as JK2's counterexample shows and see [this FreeDictionary article](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Countable-Nouns.htm#:~:text=Abstract%20Countable%20Nouns,concepts%2C%20feelings%2C%20or%20attributes.)]).

Comment: @EdwinAshworthThere are non-countable abstract nouns. **Those** do not need a determine (the) when the **notion** is being discussed. I gave plenty of examples of that. As my link shows, most cannot be made plural. Finally, there is no other explanation for "unemployment" not having to have a determiner!

Comment: 'There are [by inference] countable abstract nouns' I would not have commented on here (though I think 'non-count noun' is unhelpful as the vast majority of nouns have both count and non-count usages). But that contradicts a global 'Abstract nouns do not require determiners.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, they do not. The notions for beauty, wealth, health, honor, trust, would never take a the. So, again, if you are referring to the basic notion of an abstract noun (non-countable), you do not need a the. AND there is no other way of explaining it.

Comment: If you accept [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/abstract-nouns/#:~:text=Ideas%2C%20emotions%2C%20personality%20traits%2C,differentiate%20them%20from%20concrete%20nouns.) as an authority, you also have to accept << Ideas, emotions, personality traits, and philosophical concepts don’t exist in the physical world—you can’t sense them or interact with them—so we call them abstract nouns to differentiate them from concrete nouns.  >> But the whole concrete/abstract analysis has been discussed here before, and found sorely lacking.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So how do you explain the use of these kinds of words without a *the* determiner? I already gave a university writing course (above) definition, which is better than Grammarly. "**An abstract noun identifies an object that you cannot see, touch, or count. There are some exceptions, but most abstract nouns cannot be made plural, so they are noncount nouns**. Examples of abstract nouns include anger, education, melancholy, softness, violence, and conduct"